# Summation of Higher Order Integrals

Tags: integration, summation, notation

Probably a noob question, but How is it the notation of the summation of Higher order Integrals .. I mean, in the derivative case we have:

$$ \frac{d f(x)}{dx} + \frac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2} + ... + \frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n} =   \sum_{m=1}^n  \frac{d^m f(x)}{dx^m}$$

In the case of Integrals how do I represent the same concept?

$$ \int f(x)dx +  \int \int f(x)f(x) dx dx + ...   $$

Since Integrals are anti-derivatives, I don't know if it is possible to do this:

$$ \frac{d^{-1} f(x)}{dx^{-1}} + \frac{d^{-2} f(x)}{dx^{-2}} + ... + \frac{d^{-n} f(x)}{dx^{-n}} =   \sum_{m=1}^n  \frac{d^{-m} f(x)}{dx^{-m}}$$

Is there a way to do the Summation of Higher order integrals using the integral notation .. Is not possible, right?

Comment: The idea doesn't carry for $dx^{-m}$ I believe but if you defined some differential operator e.g. $s$ then you can say $s^{-m}f$ you could also say something like $$\sum_{m=1}^n\int f^m(x)dx^m$$

Comment: But How do I apply the index notation above the integral sign?

Comment: If you look at the mathjax tutorial for this site there may be a guide on how to demonstrate $m$ integral signs

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I going to look at .. but I don't know ..

Comment: Look at Brians Answer he has done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the standard Leibniz integral notation, a possible notation that would be easily recognizable without additional explanation might be
$$
\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx + \iint f(x)\,\mathrm dx + \iiint f(x)\,\mathrm dx + \cdots
+ \int \!\!\!\!\underbrace{\cdots}_{n \text{ times}\ \ \, }\!\!\!\!\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \sum_{n=1}^N\int \!\!\!\!\underbrace{\cdots}_{n \text{ times}\ \ \, }\!\!\!\!\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx^n
$$

However, this is somewhat messy, and fills up a lot of the page which can be distracting. If you are willing to adopt an alternative notation for anti-differentiation, this can be made much more concise.

For example, taking some inspiration from history, we can use [Lagrange's Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange's_notation) to write
$$
f^{(-1)}(x) +f^{(-2)}(x) + \cdots + f^{(-n)}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N f^{(-n)}(x)
$$

Or alternatively, in [Euler's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Euler's_notation), we have
$$
D^{(-1)}f(x) +D^{(-2)}f(x) + \cdots + D^{(-n)}f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N D^{(-n)}f(x)
$$
For absolute brevity, you could even define your own differential operator, $L_n$, by
$$
L_n(f) = \int f(x)\,\mathrm dx + \iint f(x)\,\mathrm dx + \iiint f(x)\,\mathrm dx + \cdots
+ \int \!\!\!\!\underbrace{\cdots}_{n \text{ times}\ \ \, }\!\!\!\!\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
and then denote the entire sum simply by $L_n f$ where ever it might appear.

As always in mathematics, you are free to adopt whatever notation you think will more clearly convey your ideas to your reader.

Comment: so, is that the reason why Lagrange and Euler created new notations?